# How to get audio from or to an FM tuner shield for Arduino

Tags: audio, arduino

I have an Arduino Uno and a radio receiver [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) ([Si4735](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10342)). I am trying to get another audio source to either play through the currently attached 1/8th jack on the shield or have the audio from the shield piped into the Arduino, where I can redirect it to some other source.

I don't have much experience with Arduino or hardware, however I am very experienced as a software developer. Any suggestions as to where to start, or if this shield even supports either of these functionalities?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is not a good fit for [SO].  Have you tried asking this on the Arduino forums?

Comment: Yes, I have.  Good fit? it was answered quite well, maybe stack overflow has more potential than you give it credit : )

Comment: Stil doesn't belong on SO regardless ... we are trying to get an Arduino specific site on stackexchange, see the [proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41127/arduino) to commit your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the schematic](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Shields/SI4735%20Shield-v12.pdf), the audio output of the Si4735 chip is wired directly to the headphone jack -- there is no way to send the output elsewhere, or to send other audio to it.

Comment: Thank you, that was my suspicion.